# Smart Contract Invocation Issues

Tags: hyperledger-fabric

I would like to know if other blockchain node members can get the identity of the current contract caller by analyzing the peer's ledger when I execute a smart contract call using a certificate issued by Fabric CA?

I was hoping someone could help me out.

Answer (score 0):

Transactions recorded on the blockchain include identifying information (typically an X.509 certificate) for the client identity that submitted the transaction, which is used to verify that the caller has permission to access the ledger and to make ledger updates. This information within the recorded transactions can be accessed by anyone with read access to the blockchain.

For cases where client identities need to be kept completely anonymous, while still allowing access permissions to be verified, Fabric can use Identity Mixer (Idemix) instead of regular public key cryptography. Note that client API support is extremely limited. More details here:

https://hyperledger-fabric.readthedocs.io/en/release-2.5/idemix.html